# node js TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined file not getting submitted

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to upload a file to cloudinary but after submitting the form it throws a path undefined error.
it is showing req.file as undefined. how do i get the path of the file?
the error

```
undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined
    at D:\college\project web\project1 - Copy final think so - Copy\routes\campgrounds.js:49:44
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\college\project web\project1 - Copy final think so - Copy\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (D:\college\project web\project1 - Copy final think so - Copy\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at middlewareo.isloggedin (D:\college\project web\project1 - Copy final think so - Copy\middleware\index.js:48:16)
```

the post route

```
router.post("c/n/v/n", middleware.isloggedin, function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.file)
    cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(req.file.path, { resource_type: "video" }, function(error, result) { console.log(result, error); });
});
```

the form

```
        <form action="/c/n/v/n" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <h2 style="text-align: center;">Add video</h2>
            <div style="width: 30%; margin: 20px auto;">
                <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="cat[name]" placeholder="name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="number" name="cat[price]" placeholder="Price">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="file" name="file" accept="video/*" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="cat[description]" class="form-control" placeholder="description">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">submit!!</button></div>
                <a href="/c">Go back</a>
            </div>
        </form>
```

the EDIT if video1:[{url:string,format:string}]
for multiple files

```
 router.post("/n/v/n", upload.array('images'), middleware.isloggedin, async function(req, res) {
    try {
        req.body.ca.video1 = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < req.files.length; i++) {

            console.log(req.files[i].path);
            cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(req.files[i].path, { resource_type: "auto" },  function(error, result) {

                req.body.ca.video1.push({
                    url: result.secure_url,
                    format: result.format
                });
                req.body.ca.author = {
                    id: req.user._id,
                    username: req.user.username
                }
                req.body.ca.created = new Date();

                ////if i get out of this then req.body.ca becomes undefined
                const campground = await Campground.create(req.body.ca);
            });
/////here the video1 goes undefined
        }

        req.flash("success", "it is uploading");
        res.redirect("/c");
    } catch (err) {
        req.flash("error", err.message);
        res.redirect("back");
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`multipart/form-data` requests are not processed by default by Express.js, you need to add dedicate middleware to process them, like the supported [expressjs/multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) package, with `npm i --save multer`.

Then you need to update your request handle to include multer upload middleware, like:

```js
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });

//... 
router.post("c/n/v/n", upload.single('file'), middleware.isloggedin, function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.file)
    cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(req.file.path, { resource_type: "video" }, function(error, result) { console.log(result, error); });
});
```

Here we're using `upload.single('fieldName')` where `fieldName` is the name specified in the HTML form.

Now `req.file` should be populated.

Comment: when i try to upload now it is showing [object Object]

Comment: It's correct, req.file is an object, and req.file.path is local path https://github.com/expressjs/multer#file-information

Comment: no the page goes blank with [object Object] only showing in the webpage the file does not gets uploaded

Comment: You should check errors in console, and use res.render res.redirect or res.json in order to send a response from express to the client

Comment: how do i  write it for upload.array  such that it gets the path of every file.  the code is up in the edit

Comment: plus multer({dest : 'uploads/'}) is creating a directory uploads which is taking server side sapce + cloudinary space both for same file

Comment: Yup, that's true, just placed it as an example for the particular request. Using `os.tmpdir()` or just streaming the upload with busboy would be better, but it is more complicated.

Comment: can you look at the post route  (above) for multiple file it is creating a new entry everytime it is looping how do i fix it.